# GWT's CellTable loading bar won't display while refreshing contents

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gwt-2.2-celltable

I do the following:

1. Create the CellTable (loading bar
   displays)
2. Put data in it (loading bar disappears, data appears)

I now want to:

1. Clear data and show the loading bar
2. Put more data in it (loading bar disappears, data appears)

Has anyone done this? I've tried a few methods but they seem like hacks and haven't worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GWT trunk there is a [revision r9687](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=9687&path=/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.java) just for your case, which sadly wasn't included in latest GWT-2.2 release:

***Log message***

> Adding a LoadingStateEvent to CellList and CellTable so users can receive an
> event when the data is loaded. Now, LoadingState is a first class citizen (an interface so users can define their own loading state).  Both CellList and CellTable now support
> setting a custom loading indicator Widget and a custom Widget to display when
> the table is empty.

Comment: Thanks.  Hopefully this is released with 2.3... and soon.